# PCL Attribute not seen in MVC ModelMetaDataProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, portable-class-library

I have a small PCL attribute to display a string for enum values:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class EnumDescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string description;
    public EnumDescriptionAttribute(string description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public string Description { get { return description; } }
}
```

I have made a CustomMetadataProvider for my MVC Project like that:

```
public class CustomMetadatprovider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var modelMetadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        if (attributes.OfType<EnumDescriptionAttribute>().Any())
        {
            modelMetadata.DisplayName = attributes.OfType<EnumDescriptionAttribute>().First().Description;
        }

        return modelMetadata;
    }
}
```

The enum where I apply the attribute on:

```
public enum RequestStatus
{
    [EnumDescription("Unknown value")]
    Unknown = 0,
    [EnumDescription("New value")]
    New = 10,
    [EnumDescription("In Progress value")]
    InProgress = 20,
    [EnumDescription("Terminated value")]
    Terminated = 30,
    [EnumDescription("Canceled value")]
    Cancelled = 40
}
```

In my startup.cs:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomMetadatprovider();
```

I go through the my custom metada provider but my attribute is never listed on the field.

Am I missing Something?

**EDIT**

I made some progress, the attribute is seen if I apply it to the ViewModel like this:

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [EnumDescription("Provider are you seeing me?")]
    public RequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

The metadataprovider is not seeing the EnumDescriptionAttribute on Status value

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public RequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you register the provider in `Global.asax.cs`?

Comment: If you didn't install `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`, I think you still need to register it in `Global.asax.cs`

Comment: The code of my CustomMetadataProvider is running for each request. I can break on it.

Comment: You apply the attribute on a field. But fields are not eligible to be bound. properties are. So, change `AttributeTargets.Field` to `AttributeTargets.Property` and apply the attribute on properties.

Comment: It's an enum AttributeTargets must be Field

Comment: Then why not use `[Display(Name = "Unknown value")]`...? And if you are using MVC5 `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(t => t.Status )`

Comment: Because this enum is used in a Xamarin App

Comment: I modified the AttributeTargets to `AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property` and working for me

Comment: I've already tried it and it didn't work... I will make a POC and see if it works!